# Am I performance testing correctly? Library "Memored" storage vs. normal RAM storage in Node.js

Tags: node.js, performance-testing

I am trying to compare the READ performance of a library called [Memored](https://github.com/PaquitoSoft/memored) to regular old RAM variables in Node.js.

I expected that the data stored with Memored to be at least slightly slower than RAM storage in terms of reading data, but the results show the opposite (read below for my outputs).

I am running this in the terminal of Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. It’s all being done in Typescript, which gets compiled down to JavaScript later and then run with the "node" command.

This is my RAM test:

```
var normalRAM = {
    firstname: 'qwe',
    lastname: 'fsa'
}

var s = process.hrtime(); //start timer
console.log(normalRAM); // read from ram
var e = process.hrtime(s) //stop timer

console.log("end0", e[0]);  //results in seconds
console.log("end1", e[1]);  //results in nanoseconds
```

This is my Memored test:

```
// Clustering needed to show Memored in action
if (cluster.isMaster)
{
    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else
{
    var han = {
        firstname: 'Han',
        lastname: 'Solo'
    }

    // Store and read
    memored.store('character1', han, function ()
    {
        console.log('Value stored!');
        var hrstart = process.hrtime(); // start timer
        memored.read('character1', function (err: any, value: any)
        {
            var hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart) // stop timer
            console.log('Read value:', value);

            console.log("hrend0", hrend[0]); //results in seconds
            console.log("hrend1", hrend[1]); //results in nanoseconds

        });
    });
}
```

The results:

```
The RAM read speeds are around 6500000 nanoseconds.

The Memored read speeds are around 1000000 nanoseconds
```

Am I testing the speeds incorrectly here? What are the flaws in my methodology? Perhaps my initial assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I switched the following two lines:

```
var hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart) // stop timer
console.log('Read value:', value);
```

To this:

```
console.log('Read value:', value);
var hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart) // stop timer
```

Which makes more sense in a real scenario since I would need to read it from RAM like that anyway after the data is returned. The answer to my question is probably "your Memored test is performing faster, because it’s only testing when the data comes back for my callback to use, and not when I actually read it from the 'value' variable".

Comment: I forgot to mention that the measured time increased to the expected time after I made this change.